# How to adapt `sudo yum install ...` instructions to install packages under `$HOME/.hostdir` without superuser privileges?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

How can I adapt the following instructions

```
sudo yum install asciidoc xmlto epel-release docbook2X
```

...so that I can run them without superuser privileges, and the installation happens under `--prefix=$HOME/.hostdir`?

In particular, how can I at least *download* the `yum` packages mentioned above?

---

In case it matters, this is part of an effort to install `git` under `$HOME/.hostdir`, without superuser privileges.

The following worked fine

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.11.0.tar.xz
tar xf git-2.11.0.tar.xz
cd git-2.11.0
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.hostdir
make all
make install
```

...but I was not able to build the `git` docs.  Both `make doc` and `make info` failed with

```
/bin/sh: line 1: asciidoc: command not found
```

The `sudo yum` line quoted earlier was adapted from [these instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) for building `git` from source.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only download rpm packages you can `--downloadonly` to do it, with following syntax.

```
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

But most rpm packages will require root privileges for install as they are installed in system folders usually.

You can also search for needed packages on online rpm databases like http://rpm.pbone.net/ or https://www.rpmfind.net/ and just download them from direct links, but you will again need root privileges for rpm install, as they install packages for all users.

You need to manually download and compile from source commands you need.

From what I see you can just download asciidoc script to your home folder, and put it in your users path, and it should be found, without installing any rpms.

http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/INSTALL.html